# Using Lidar CUDA dataframe

Tags: lidar

I have to convert ellipsoidal height to Mean sea level on 5 million points which only possible on GPU segments.

Below is my code

```
import cudf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from laspy.file import File
import gdal 
import pyproj
from numba import cuda
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline as Spline


infile=File("pointcloud.las",mode='r')
lasfile_df = cudf.DataFrame()
lasfile_df['X']=infile.x
lasfile_df['Y']=infile.y
lasfile_df['Z']=infile.z
# http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm96/binary/binarygeoid.html
# Download WW15MGH.DAC
egm=np.fromfile("/content/drive/MyDrive/WW15MGH.DAC",">i2").reshape(721,1440)/100

@cuda.jit
def ellipsoid_to_msl(lon,lat,height,out):
  for i,(lon,lat,height) in enumerate(zip(lon,lat,height)):
    longs=np.arange(0,360,0.25)
    lats=np.arange(-90,90.1,0.25)
    interp=Spline(lats,longs,egm)
    lat*=-1
    if lon<0:
        lon+=360
    z=interp.ev(lat,lon)
    out[i]=height-z
lasfile_df=lasfile_df.apply_rows(ellipsoid_to_msl,
                                 incols={'X':'lon','Y':'lat','Z':'height'},
                                 outcols={'out': np.float64},
                                 kwargs={})
```

In the lasfile_df, the apply_rows is not working properly.

Can anyone explain how to do it using a cuda dataframe because in a pandas dataframe it takes a lot of time?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I doubt you can just chuck scipy code into a jjitted function and have it work.  Beyond that there are some more basic problems, like the fact that you loop over a variable and also re-assign it (might technically work but bad practice) and the fact that you're re-creating arrays and re-instantiating the interpolator on every iteration unnecessarily.  If you optimize your code you likely won't need to worry about using the GPU

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. By the way, the speed of computation takes care of by the NumPy library and I correct it by removing it for a loop.